# Match 2 columns in sheet 1 to 2 columns in sheet 2 and pull value from 3rd column

Tags: microsoft-excel

I want to pull from sheet 1 the Unit value to populate Sheet 2 Unit cell
but need an exact Match of Sheet 1 column Type and Number to Sheet 2 Type and Number

```
Sheet 1                     Sheet 2                                     
Unit    Type    Number      Unit    Type    Number
88      Test    1                   Trade   1
77      Pack    2                   Pack    2
66      Card    3                   Card    3
55      Test    4                   Herd    4
44      Group   5                   Group   5
```

Looking for the results as

```
Sheet 2
Unit    Type    Number
        Trade   1
77      Pack    2
66      Card    3
        Herd    4
44      Group   5
```

Tried

```
=INDEX(Sheet1!A2:A6,MATCH(Sheet1!B2:B6&Sheet1!C2:C6,Sheet2!B2:B6&Sheet2!C2:C6,0))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Microsoft 365, **[xlookup](https://exceljet.net/excel-functions/excel-xlookup-function)** is the solution of choice.

**[This site](https://www.excel-university.com/vlookup-on-two-or-more-criteria-columns/)** explains in detail two solutions:

1. If the data that you want to return is numeric, using `SUMIFS` is
   easiest in my opinion.
2. If you can insert a column, using a concatenated key is pretty
       simple.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your table is in `A1:C6`

If you have O365 with the `FILTER` function:

```
=IFERROR(FILTER(Sheet1!$A$2:$A$6,(B2=Sheet1!$B$2:$B$6)*(C2=Sheet1!$C$2:$C$6)),"")
```

If you don't have the Filter function:

```
=IFERROR(AGGREGATE(14,6,1/((Sheet1!$B$2:$B$6=B2)*(Sheet1!$C$2:$C$6=C2) )*Sheet1!$A$2:$A$6,1),"")
```